# Excel: Simplified SUMs with multiple sheets

Tags: excel

I am having troubel figuring this one out using *names*. To start, take this example

```
Sheet 1                       Sheet 2
                         |
    A           B        |    A           B
                         | 
    Labor       1000     |    Labor        200
    Material    1000     |    Material     200
                         |
    ...                  |    ...
                         |
    Labor        500     |    Labor        100
    Material     500     |    Material     100
```

**The Question**: I'd like to be able to total the Labor and Material values up for `n` number of sheets. The default template starts with two (2) sheets but the user may add any number of sheets they would like.

**The Problem** (as I see it): The user can add as many **"special"** page specific item pricing lines to the top of the page. Below that, however, every section (the Labor/Material calculations) are uniformly offset.

If anybody could help me out on this one I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is a VBA solution okay? (you could do it with formulas, but with VBA you could vary the number of sheets).  Also, would any of the page specific item pricing lines contain the words "Labor" or "Materials"?

Comment: VBA is fine. I used `Labor` and `Material` as examples, but there are actually a number of lines with various descriptions. So the short answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the meat of it, I'm having trouble with some of the surround, but I'll update

```
For i = 1 To counts
   For Each wkst In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      wkst.Activate
      tots(i) = tots(i) + WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A:A"), categories(i), Range("B:B"))

   Next
Next
```

Where `categories` is an array that holds "Labor","Material", etc.,`tots` is an array of doubles (or integers if there won't be any dollar amounts), and `counts` is the number of elements in `categories`.

Comment: I figured it would end up being a VBA solution... bummer, but it is what it is. Thanks!